# How to use case sensitive SQL and C# database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I'm trying to run a raw query in the Postgresql database, but when I try, I get the following error:

> ERROR:  relation "cards" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT * FROM Cards

My table name is `Cards` as it is in the string and not `cards`.

Code:

```
var cards = _context.Cards;
var query = cards.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Cards").ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, but some searching leads me to believe you could do: `cards.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM \"Cards\" ")`. In other words `Cards` needs to be double quoted `"Cards"` to preserve the case otherwise as the error pointed out it is down cased to `cards`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This works very well, thaaanks!!!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS